# Cocos3D: weird line between adjuscent 3d planes

Tags: tiles, blender, tilemap, cocos3d

I have created a textured plane in blender of size 2×2 and I am using that as a tile. This is the screenshot of what I have done in blender. Nothing special, the default plane on origin, I just added a texture.

[image]

I exported this plane to iPhone as POD file. And using below code, I created my tile map.

```
//getting the tile
CC3MeshNode * greenSlate  = (CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed:@"GreenSlate"];

CC3Vector greenSize       = [self returnSizeOfNode:greenSlate];

//This one printed as 2.0, 0.0, 2.0 .     
NSLog(@"greenSlate : %f  %f %f", greenSize.x, greenSize.y, greenSize.z);

float xOffset           =   -3;
float zOffset           =   -3;

for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        CC3MeshNode * mesh  =   nil;

        float xStart        =   xOffset;
        float zStart        =   zOffset;

        mesh            =   [greenSlate copy];

        xStart          =   xOffset + column * greenSize.x;
        zStart          =   zOffset + row * greenSize.z;

        mesh.location   =   cc3v(xStart , 0  , zStart);
        mesh.visible    =   YES;

        //add to scene
        [self addChild:mesh];
    }
}
```

And when I run on simulator, I am getting this.

[image]

The tiles are at correct position, but there is a black line between each tile. How can I remove these lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved it. The issue was pretty basic, and I guess basics is what I haven't learn about openGL.

I was using a texture of dimension 200 x 200, but openGL requires textures to be the power of 2 to avoid rounding artifacts. So I **changed my texture to 256 x 256, and voila the black lines went away**.

One other thing causing this weird lines is explained [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/setting-multiple-textures-on-a-cc3planenode/).

Answer (score 1):

Guess this is a rounding issue. Have you tried rounding your vertex coordinates?

Comment: I thought of that too.. The size of one tile is 2 x 2.. And the xStart and yStart in the above code takes values : -3.0, -1.0, 1.0 (I did an NSLog) which is round I think.

Comment: Just to be sure, what happens when rendering white untextured quads? Since you're not reusing vertices, I'd try letting them overlap a tiny bit. This can be hardware and resolution dependent, but I'd try some small value.

Comment: Super @Mario, yes.. When I run untextured quads, there is no lines in between.. Oops and I need it to be textured.

Comment: Then there's something happening with your texture, try playing around with texture quality/filtering options as well as texture wrapping.